# Probability of wearing a coat & having it snow.

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I haven't been able to solve this, could you please help?

**Steve has lived in Boston for a long time. From experience, he knows that each day has a 5%
chance to be snowy. Steve looks ahead to the next 10 days.**

**Steve decides that, without checking the weather, he will wear his heavy coat to work 3 of
those days. What is the probability Steve will wear his coat on at least one snowy day?**

Thank you

Comment: From [experience, I am certain that it won't rain if you bring your umbrella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias). A corollary is that it won't snow in Boston when Steve wears his heavy coat :)

Comment: [also relevant](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Umbrella%20Rule)

Answer (score 3):

The $7$ days on which Steve does not wear his heavy coat on are irrelevant. He has chosen the three days on which he will wear his heavy coat, and on each of these three days, there is a $5\%$ chance of snow.

The probability that it will snow on *at least* one of these days is $1$ minus the probability that it will snow on *none* of these days. This is $$1-0.95^3 = 0.142625 = \boxed{\,14.2625\%\,\,}$$